# Como posso ver a estrutura de uma tabela em SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Em MySQL, podemos usar o comando `DESC <table>` para poder descobrir a estrutura de uma tabela.

E em SQLite? Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Quem deu o negativo, poderia explicar o motivo? O que poderia ser melhorado na pergunta?

Comment: Não fui eu. Mas acho que é `.schema <table>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Algo mais próximo ao comando `DESCRIBE [tabela]` do MySQL:

```
PRAGMA table_info([tabela]);
```

Caso queira algo mais detalhado:

```
.schema [tabela]
```

Também pode obter tudo invocando somente `.schema` sem especificar uma tabela.

```
.schema
```

Adicionalmente, é interessante também saber o equivalente ao `SHOW TABLES;`

O comando é `.tables` ou `.ta`

obs: *[tabela]* é um escopo ilustrativo. Deve digitar o nome da tabela sem os colchetes. ex:

```
PRAGMA table_info(minha_tabela);

.schema minha_tabela
```

Comment: Ótimo, acho que o `PRAGMA table_info([table])` foi o mais próximo do `DESCRIBLE [table]` +1

Answer (score 6):

Se estiver o interpretador basta usar `.schema nome_da_tabela`. Ele vai mostrar a *query* que grou isso para você. Ele não tem um mecanismo específico.

Também pode [chamar uma função que dê essa informação](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info). Isto é feito com o `PRAGMA schema.table_info('nome_da_tabela')`

Mas em sua aplicação provavelmente vai querer fazer diferente e consultar o tabela de estruturas:

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='nome_da_tabela';
```

No SQLite 3.16 já pode fazer:

```
SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info('nome_da_tabela');
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/ListTable.sql).

Lembrando que o SQLite possui é um banco de dados de tipagem dinâmica.